# Get specified range

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, filter, setvalue

I have a table of data in a sheet that contains 7 columns of data. I would like to take only the first 5 columns of data from that table and populate it into another sheet. However, when I run my code it populates all 7 columns into the other sheet, which I don't want. How can I correct this? A portion of my script is below.

```
//Section D: Setting filter criteria based on dates in Data Overview sheet.
var filteredData = rngData.filter(function(row)
{var date = row[0]; return date >= beginDate_current && date <= endDate_current});


//Section E: Setting filtered data into Current Month table in Summarized Data sheet.
sheet3.getRange("B7").getDataRegion().offset(6,0).clearContent();
sheet3.getRange(7,3,filteredData.length,filteredData[5].length).setValues(filteredData);
sheet3.getRange(7,3,filteredData.length,filteredData[5].length).sort([{column: 3, ascending: 
true}]);
debugger
}
```

Comment: Show how you get `rgnData`

Comment: `const sheet2 = ss.getSheetByName('Data Overview');
 const rngData = sheet2.getDataRange().getValues();`. Sheet 2 has the table with 7 columns.

Comment: Try `const rngData = sheet2.getRange(1,1,sheet2.getLastRow(),5).getValues();`

Comment: This worked, thank you.